I'm getting a bottom underline in the TabBar. How to remove it?
I'm getting a bottom underline in the TabBar. I tried to remove it. but its not removing.
(https://i.sstatic.net/CbDf57Nr.png)
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TabController tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Palette.white,
      body:  Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0x1E767680), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
              height: 36,
              child: TabBar(
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                ),
                controller: tabController,
                labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF5B5B5B), fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                indicatorWeight: 0,
                indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(text: 'Page 1'),
                  Tab(text: 'Page 2'),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            //TabBarView
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: tabController,
                children: [
                  _buildAttendanceView(),
                  Tab2(),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ), );

I tried,
border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent)  to remove any visible border.
indicatorWeight: 0:
indicatorColor: Colors.transparent:
Wrap the TabBar widget inside a Material widget and set borderOnForeground to false.
but didnt work.

Try below code, add dividerColor: Colors.transparent, Read more about dividerColor
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0x1E767680),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
        height: 36,
        child: TabBar(
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
          indicator: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
            color: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
          controller: tabController,
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 13,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFF5B5B5B),
              fontSize: 13,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          indicatorWeight: 0,
          dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          tabs: const [
            Tab(text: 'Page 1'),
            Tab(text: 'Page 2'),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      const SizedBox(height: 16),
      //TabBarView
      Expanded(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text("Page 1"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("Page 2"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);

Result-> 

Glad to help you, enjoy your ride with Flutter.

It sounds like you're dealing with an unwanted underline or border at the bottom of the TabBar. You’ve already tried some approaches like setting indicatorWeight to 0, indicatorColor to transparent, and wrapping the TabBar in a Material widget, but the underline persists.
To remove the underline, try the following adjustments:
1. Set the indicator to null:
If you don't want any underline or indicator at all, you can set the indicator property of the TabBar to null.
2. Remove the indicatorWeight:
Ensure that the indicatorWeight is completely removed since setting it to 0 might still cause issues.
Here’s how your code could look with these adjustments:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  TabController tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Palette.white,
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color(0x1E767680), 
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)
          ),
          height: 36,
          child: TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            indicator: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
            ),
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, 
              fontSize: 13, 
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
            ),
            unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFF5B5B5B), 
              fontSize: 13, 
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
            ),
            tabs: const [
              Tab(text: 'Page 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Page 2'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 16),
        // TabBarView
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: [
              _buildAttendanceView(),
              Tab2(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

3. Ensure the TabBar is not inside a Material widget with a borderOnForeground setting:
If you have wrapped the TabBar inside a Material widget elsewhere, ensure that borderOnForeground is not interfering.
4. Check for Other Widgets:
If none of the above works, double-check other widgets wrapping the TabBar, like Container or any parent Material widget, to ensure they aren’t causing any unintended styling issues.
This should resolve the unwanted underline in the TabBar. If the issue persists, please let me know, and we can explore further adjustments.

Those not working. Maybe its not the border. something else that giving in default.  I already checked with chatgpt. its not solving too.
